# Is an hybrid application better in performance rather than a native application

Tags: android, ios, performance, hybrid-mobile-app

I would like to know which kind of application is better in performance and speed.

I came across from the link that uber and paytm application are hybrid application. Is it true? It's hard to belive..

[native or hybrid](http://blog.venturepact.com/8-high-performance-apps-you-never-knew-were-hybrid/)

Comment: Prefer *native* application instead of *hybrid* if you want better performance , scalability , speed.

Comment: in which kind of scenarios i will go for hybrid application??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Native applications are faster**.

---

Now that being state obviously it depends also on the code quality.

**Example**:

- `App1` is Native
- `App2` is Hybrid

If `App1` has a better infrastructure, code, etc.. it will be faster. But if App1 is not optimized, and not well writen and `App2`  is optimized App2 will be faster.

Obviously it also depends **how** and with **which technologies** you are writing your hybrid app.

---

### Chart (by mr-productivity)

[image]

Comment: is uber application is a native app??

Comment: @DineshkumarArunachalam Uber is Hybrid

Comment: in which kind of scenarios i will go for hybrid application??

Comment: @DineshkumarArunachalam Checkout the chart I've just added, it depends in a lot of factors like budget, time, audience, scalability, features... there's a lot of things that should be considered before deciding

Comment: can you give some good examples for coding  pattern like mvc  in android ?? and do's and dont  in android programming  ..

Comment: I am sorry but that's out of scope on SO  but feel free to contact me on skype (daniaal.95) and it will be my pleasure to help as far as I can

Comment: There's also Xamarin, which compiles to native code so avoids the performance and look and feel issues with HTML based hybrid apps.

Comment: @nasch Indeed i specified also that it depends on the technologies, but thanks for point out :)

Comment: Yeah I only mentioned it because it isn't in that nice chart.

Answer (score 0):

Native is faster than hybrid in most of the cases. 
mainly performance based on what technologies you have used and how you written code.

Assume we will take equally optimized coded app in hybrid and native. native is bit faster than hybrid. 
Overall observation about performance, when you are using graphical related (games, photo shops etc..), device oriented, OS dependent app and high secured then you please give preference to Native app.

When you are going to replace the Web application to Mobile app,graphical related (games, photo shops etc..),minimum device oriented, fast development, low cost and reusable to many platform then you can choose hybrid app.